# how to get a realtime return value from an infinite loop thread in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, infinite-loop, python-multithreading

I am trying to make a thread that constantly reads from my robot's sensors, so I can use the outputed "steering" value in different run cases for the motors, as to be able to run the motors on rotations, on time, etc. I have found something similar ([Python returning values from infinite loop thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48429653/python-returning-values-from-infinite-loop-thread)), but this did not help, as it only printed the values when I broke the loop (ie : disconnecting the sensor). Here is my code :

```
from sensor_and_motor_startup import *
import threading
import queue

DEFAULT_SPEED = 60

# PID Values --These are subjective and need to be tuned to the robot and mat
# Kp must be augmented or decreased until the robot follows the line smoothly --Higher Kp = Stronger corrections
# Same with Ki, after Kp is done --- note, Ki is not used in this case (error accumulation)
# Kd to 1, and move up or done until smooth, after Kp and Ki
# This process can take a VERY long time to fine-tune
K_PROPORTIONAL = 0.2
K_INTEGRAL = 0
K_DERIVATIVE = 0


class OneSensorLineFollower:
    target = 24
    error = 0
    last_error = 0
    derivative = 0
    integral = 0

    def __init__(self, color_sensor):
        self.__color_sensor = color_sensor

    def follower(self, side_of_line=None, kp=K_PROPORTIONAL):
        if side_of_line is None:
            side_of_line = self.SideOfLine.left
        else:
            side_of_line = self.SideOfLine.right
        self.error = self.target - (self.__color_sensor.value(3) / 2)
        self.integral = self.error + self.integral
        self.derivative = self.error - self.last_error
        motor_steering = ((self.error * kp) + (self.integral * K_INTEGRAL) + (self.derivative * K_DERIVATIVE
                                                                                          )) * float(side_of_line)
        self.last_error = self.error
        return motor_steering

    class SideOfLine:
        left = 1
        right = -1


def hisp_center_corrector(out_que):
    while True:
        follow = OneSensorLineFollower(left_side_sensor)
        steering = follow.follower(kp=0.15)
        out_que.put(steering)
        sleep(0.1)


def low_speed_follower(speed=DEFAULT_SPEED, rotations=5):
    follower = OneSensorLineFollower(center_sensor)
    steer_pair.on_for_rotations(follower.follower(kp=0.3), speed, rotations)


que = queue.Queue()
t = threading.Thread(target=hisp_center_corrector, args=(que,))
t.start()
t.join()
while True:
    value = que.get()
    print(value)
```

Comment: As I remember it, you need to put things **in** the queue before you can take them out...Perhaps that is part of the problem? You should edit your post to include what your script outputs and how it differs from what you are expecting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `.join()` which makes your main thread to wait for that thread to finish.

Start your thread as a deamon and don't join it:

```
threading.Thread(target=hisp_center_corrector, args=(que,), daemon=True).start()
```

Otherwise your `value = que.get()` code won't run.

Comment: @ArthurGoetzke-Coburn if you get your answer, please consider accepting the answer by clicking green check mark.

Comment: Oh yeah, new to this, sorry, did it now