# Python called via C# not returning value when in infinite loop

Tags: c#, python

I'm currently implementing a .Net app, which connects to a Raspberry SenseHat. To do so, I'm using the Python implementation https://pythonhosted.org/sense-hat/ and call the python scripts via Processes to be as loosely coupled as possible.
Everything works fine, but I have some problems with the joystick: The example uses an infinite loop in the Python script. My "Joystock.py" script is currently looking like this:

```
import sys
try:
   import queue
except ImportError:
   import Queue as queue
import threading
import requests

from sense_hat import SenseHat
sense = SenseHat()

# Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48429653/python-returning-values-from-infinite-loop-thread
def _listen(queue):
  while True:
    event = sense.stick.wait_for_event(emptybuffer=True)
    val = event.action + ":" + event.direction
    queue.put(val)

def listen(params):
  q = queue.Queue()
  t1 = threading.Thread(target=_listen, name=_listen, args=(q,))
  t1.start()

  while True:
    value = q.get()
    print(value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  args = sys.argv
  args.pop(0) # Remove file path
  methodName = args.pop(0) # Pop method name

  globals()[methodName](args)
```

The bottom part is to pass the method name and the parameters I'd like to call via arguments.
My C# call is looking like this:

```
public void Listen(PythonListeningRequest request)
{
    var startInfo = _startInfoFactory.CreateForListening(request);

    var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.OutputDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input: " + e.Data);
    };

    process.ErrorDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Data);
    };
}
```

And the definition of the ProcessStartInfo:

```
public ProcessStartInfo CreateForListening(PythonRequest request)
{
    return new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = FindPythonExeFilePath(),
        Arguments = CreateArgumentsString(request),
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    };
}

private static string CreateArgumentsString(PythonRequest request)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(request.FilePath);
    sb.Append(" ");

    sb.Append(request.MethodName);
    sb.Append(" ");

    foreach (var arg in request.Arguments)
    {
        sb.Append(arg.AsString());
        sb.Append(" ");
    }

    var result = sb.ToString();
    return result;
}

private string FindPythonExeFilePath()
{
    var possibleFilePaths = new string[]
    {
        @"C:\Users\mlm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe",
        @"C:\WINDOWS\py.exe",
        "/usr/bin/python"
    };

    var existingPythonPath = possibleFilePaths.FirstOrDefault(fp => _fileSystem.File.Exists(fp));
    Guard.That(() => existingPythonPath != null, "No python path found.");

    return existingPythonPath;
}
```

As you can see in the python part, there is a queue used, which I've got from another SO question. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work, as soon as "t1.start()" is in the code, I never get a return value.

Trying the python script manually works fine, so I guess the problem is the Process connection to C#? Unfortuntely, I didn't find anything related to this behavior, has therefore anyone any idea, what could cause this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottom line : use `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` followed by `flush()` on either stream and avoid `print`

Since I am not able to have SenseHat, I downsized your example to:

```
try:
    import queue
except ImportError:
    import Queue as queue
import threading
import time
import sys

# Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48429653/python-returning-values-from-infinite-loop-thread
def _listen(queue):
    val =0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        val = val+1
        queue.put(val)


def listen(params):
    q = queue.Queue()
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=_listen, name=_listen, args=(q,))
    t1.start()

    while True:
        value = q.get()
        sys.stdout.write(str(value) + '\n')
        sys.stdout.flush()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = sys.argv
    args.pop(0)  # Remove file path
    methodName = args.pop(0)  # Pop method name

    globals()[methodName](args)
```

as for the C# part I didn't change a thing just got rid of the `class PythonRequest`

This seems to work. Whereas with `print(value)` instead of `sys.stdout.write(str(value) + '\n') sys.stdout.flush()` I was not getting any return value from the callback `OutputDataReceived`

So I believe you have to write on `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` then force `flush` to write on a stream piped to your C#. Otherwise using `print` fills the stdout buffer and does not necessarily flush.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much. One question: Should I alwaays use stdout instead of print? Are there any major differences except the threading issues?

Comment: Interesting, I'm currently testing on the Raspberry PI, the solution works only without loop and has a huge delay. With a loop I don't get any response again.

Comment: All things considered I think the issue is really flushing. I have tired with `print str(value) sys.stdout.flush()` and it also works for me. So you can use `print` it's just that since the `flush` method is only available on stream I think it is clearer to use `sys.stdout`, moreover you have control over whether what you send to the C# has a '\n' or not.

Comment: I have tired on my raspberry. I am not seeing any problem on my part. But again I miss the part concerning SenseHat...